# Документа нет, хотя в mongo compass я добавлял документ

Tags: mongodb

я только разбираюсь с mongodb, но я столкнулся с такой проблемой - я добавляю данные в коллекцию через mongodb compass, а когда проверяю через консоль данные, то он мне ничего не выводит, а count выводит 0. Mongodb я переустанавливал. Что делать?
[image]

Comment: Напишете сначала `use shop`

Comment: Да, действительно работает